# UIApplication crash when open the app after few days

Tags: ios, crash

Could you help me with this mysterious crash? It happens when I re-open the app after a few days, so it's practically impossible to debug it :/

Any clue or idea would be super helpful. I'm kinda lost here. Thank you!

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000196a63bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x000000018ab35418 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
2  UIKit                          0x000000018ab1e52c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 612
3  UIKit                          0x000000018ab34db4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 592
4  UIKit                          0x000000018ab34a40 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 700
5  UIKit                          0x000000018ab2df94 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 684
6  UIKit                          0x000000018ab0168c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
7  UIKit                          0x000000018ada060c _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14992
8  UIKit                          0x000000018aaffbf4 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1616
9  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018630a9ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
10 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186309c90 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
11 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000186307d40 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
12 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001862350a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
13 GraphicsServices               0x000000018f3d75a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
14 UIKit                          0x000000018ab66aa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
15 Wiretap                        0x000000010012b604 main (main.m:16)
16 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001970bea08 start + 4
```

Comment: Have you used the profiler in the simulator to examine memory use? Is it leaking memory? Is it holding a resource open that the OS eventually needs so it's killing your app?  Are you running a lot of tasks so something has to eventually be killed no matter what?  What about intercepting applicationWillTerminate in the appDelegate? And checking whether didReceiveMemoryWarning() is being called in your VCs?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with a touch event.  Is your initial view controller doing anything with a touch event that could possibly not be initialized by the time the event is received?

Comment: Try setting an exception breakpoint to have Xcode pause debugging at the point the exception is thrown.